# Can't resolve 'http2' error when importing Clarifai API

Tags: reactjs, api, import

I have an issue I can not seem to resolve, I am new to this and don't know whether there is something wrong in my code or the server is simply not available.

I am trying to import face recognition API from Clarifai into React App, followed the npm guide how to install, but once I do

```js
import {ClarifaiStub, grpc} from "clarifai-nodejs-grpc";
```

I get an error

```
./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/server.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'http2' in 'C:\Users\mkura\Documents\GitHub\find-the-face\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src'
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'
```

Actualy, there is `const {ClarifaiStub, grpc} = require("clarifai-nodejs-grpc");` in the guide, which I changed to

```js
import {ClarifaiStub, grpc} from "clarifai-nodejs-grpc";
```

assuming I have to import it this way. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Check what version of node you're using and what version this package supports. Perhaps you're trying to run a node package (that relies on nodes standard library) in the browser?

Comment: I am on the latest version of node. Will look it up what version it requires

Comment: You can't run a node app in the browser if it used the std lib... I suspect this is your issue here

Comment: can You explain please? not sure what You mean.

Comment: Wrote an answer with a bunch of links that hopefully explain this well @martinK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question I assert that you're trying to install the [Clarifai node API](https://github.com/Clarifai/clarifai-nodejs-grpc) into a react app.

That fails because this package is a node app using standard library features like [http2](https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html) which are not available in the browser.

Instead of the `clarifai-nodejs-grpc` you will have to use [`clarifai`](https://github.com/Clarifai/clarifai-javascript) in your react app from what I can see in their docs.

Comment: will try that and see what happens, will let you know